# Flutter Error: The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart

Error: The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formatter = LastUpdatedDateFormatter(
      lastUpdated: _endpointsData != null ? _endpointsData.values[Endpoint.cases]!.date : null,
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`?` next to the type declaration means that a variable is nullable, meaning it can accept a `null` value

For example: `String? a = null` is valid, while `String bar = null` is not a valid statement.

In your expression `lastUpdated: _endpointsData != null ? _endpointsData.values[Endpoint.cases]!.date : null`, there is a possibility for the `lastUpdated` parameter to receive a `null` value, which it does not expect or accept. It needs to receive a `DateTime` object. Consider using a default value, for example - `DateTime.now()` instead of null:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formatter = LastUpdatedDateFormatter(
      lastUpdated: _endpointsData != null ? _endpointsData.values[Endpoint.cases]!.date : DateTime.now(),
    );
```

For more info, refer to Dart docs at https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Hi, I tried that and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I removed nulls in my statement then casted as DateTime.

lastUpdated: _endpointsData.values[Endpoint.cases]?.date as DateTime,